# GoogleMap error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I'm designing this android application that involves using Google maps. I have gotten my API_KEY from Google and have inserted it into my manifest file. but when i ran the app, all i get is an error. Below is my manifest file and also the LogCat error:

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.src.apps.myekoapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <!-- Permissions -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.src.apps.myekoapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.src.apps.myekoapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.src.apps.myekoapp.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".RSSList" />
        <activity android:name=".DetailsFragment" />
        <activity android:name=".EkoMap" />
        <activity android:name=".CallLASMA" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="My API_KEY here" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat error:

```
06-26 16:14:16.570: E/AndroidRuntime(369): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4452000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

06-26 16:14:16.570: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.t(Unknown Source)

06-26 16:14:16.570: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)

06-26 16:14:16.570: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.B(Unknown Source)

06-26 16:14:16.570: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.A(Unknown Source)

06-26 16:14:16.570: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)

06-26 16:14:16.570: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.ip(Unknown Source)

06-26 16:14:16.570: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)

06-26 16:14:16.570: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)

06-26 16:14:16.570: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreate(Unknown Source)

06-26 16:14:16.570: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onCreate(Unknown Source)

06-26 16:14:16.570: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:697)

06-26 16:14:16.570: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:900)

06-26 16:14:16.570: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:978)

06-26 16:14:16.570: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4090)

06-26 16:14:16.570: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:664)

06-26 16:14:16.570: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  ... 19 more

06-26 16:14:53.350: I/Process(369): Sending signal. PID: 369 SIG: 9
```

Please where have i gone wrong? i have seen so many tutorials on this and have followed their steps but am getting this error while theirs works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your api key directly and not a reference to values folder.

Comment: <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="Your APIcode" />

Answer (score 0):

you must add this in your Manifest file:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: ok. Are you saying i should remove the meta data i wrote there and just write what you wrote because i am kinda confused.

Comment: just add this meta tag as well and don't remove the other one,Both should be included

Comment: i have done that and i'm now getting different issue. i want to upload the question, please could you look at it and help me with it because it is also from the googlemap.java code itself.

Comment: i'm trying to upload the question and i'm bein told to wait a bit. i called it googlemaps error 2

Comment: just forward me the link for that question

Comment: i"m being told to wait for 90 minutes before i could upload it

Comment: send the text file to pankaj.gat@gmail.com i'll try to find the solution for your problem

Comment: i have finally uploaded it on stackoverflow (GoogleMap error 2)  and have sent you an email.